# Flask whit tinydb pop up this error when i try to delete a field

Tags: python-3.x, flask, raspberry-pi4, tinydb

i try to fix this error in flask , i have nearly zero experience whit flask and python,
I'm struggle for couple of days, this error pop up after i try to delete the lines I insert, and to make the web work i need to reboot the pi4
thank you

part of the code wher the error print out

```
def index():
phones = d.all()#.sort(key=byPosition)
if phones == None:
    phones = []
return render_template("index.html", phones=phones)
```

[Code what pop up the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0S0sP.png)

Comment: In line 2, the indentation isn't correct.

Comment: @toyotaSupra u can guide me how i ca fix it please

Comment: In line 2 to 4 should be inside def function.

Comment: i never code in my live i will try to understand what u said and change , this is a free src from git hub  and sometimes the same error pop up in the next line   i will attach  a photo to all part of the code where the error pop up

Comment: So what does that do phones = []? Is empty or not?

Comment: No don't need to be empty, need to print on screen all the entry from tinydb @toyotaSupra

Comment: If u wanna @toyotaSupra   to I can share the link from github